How can I calculate impedance and propagation constant of coupled rectangular waveguides?
I am working on a two-port rectangular waveguide structure. I designed two different waveguides:
WG1 with width  and height ,
WG2 with the same width  but a reduced height of −2ℎ.
I am attempting to couple these waveguides in the configuration
WG1 + WG2 + WG1, as shown in the attached figure. I am looking for a theoretical expression to calculate the impedance and propagation constant of the entire structure.
I have explored approaches using an IRIS waveguide and a corrugated waveguide, but I have not been able to solve the problem. How can I calculate the impedance and propagation constant for such a structure?


Hello, I just realized I misunderstood your question and gave you a method for calculating the modes in a waveguide with the XY cross-section shown – but I think you actually are propagating through 3 segments in the Z-direction. I will deleted my answer and post a proper one.  Sorry about that.

I believe you need to treat this like a transmission line problem, making an equivalent 3-segment transmission line:
        -----+----------+-----
(Port1)  WG1     WG2      WG3   (Port 2)
        -----+----------+-----
             1          2

You need to account for the associated phase and reflection at each interface, labelled 1 & 2 here. The standing wave (combining all reflections) throughout the structure will determine your final impedance and propagation constant.
From here, you can see how to convert your parallel-plate (2D) waveguide segments to a characteristic impedance (TL equivalent), using this equation:
Zo = ɳ d / W

Where ɳ is the impedance of the core medium, which I think is ɳo in your case, or 377 Ohms. d is the y-direction height and W is the x-direction width (not specified in your drawing).
Then you need to calculate the input impedance accounting for the reflections at each interface, starting at the end (right side), as described here.
Here is the equation to calculate input Impedance of a segment accounting for the Load (on the right side of your schematic) and the Characteristic impedance (from here).

For your case, start at the right-most segment, by getting the Input Impedance looking in from 2:
...+-----...
   WG3
...+-----...
   2

Perhaps we can assume this segment extends to infinity (correct me if I'm wrong), so the Input Impedance at 2 is just the Z of WG3, let's call that impedance Z3.
So you have an equivalent circuit like this:
-----+----------+
 WG1     WG2  [Z3]
-----+----------+
     1          

Then again reduce WG2 + Z3 to an equivalent impedance, using the above Zin equation where Zload = Z3 and Zo = Z2, where Z2 is the characteristic impedance of WG2.
-----+
 WG1 [Zin of WG2 and Z3]
-----+
     1          

Then apply the same Zin equation again to get the input impedance of the entire structure.
For further reading, you will want to look up transmission line equivalent models for waveguides and review those courses/content.
Some quick google searching on the topic yields a number of good explanatory pages, such as these:

https://resources.altium.com/p/how-use-input-impedance-circuits-and-transmission-lines
https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/alternating-current/chpt-14/

